# Python: Conditional logic if entry is file or directory not working

Tags: python, file-io

I have the following directory structure on my file system:

```
/home/myUser/
    stuff_home/
        fizz/
            a.txt
            b.txt
        buzz/
            1.pdf
        widgets/
            c.txt
            2.pdf
            3.pdf
            4.pdf
```

I want to traverse `stuff_home/` recursively and count the number of subdirectories, `.txt` files and `.pdf` documents it contains. I have written a small Python script:

```
import os

dirCnt = 0
txtCnt = 0
pdfCnt = 0

def main():
    get_counts("/home/myUser/stuff_home")

    t = str(txtCnt)
    p = str(pdfCnt)
    d = str(dirCnt)
    print "\nRESULTS\Text Files:\t" + t + "\nPDF Files:\t" + p + "\nDirectories:\t" + d + "\n\n"

def get_counts(root):
    contents = os.listdir(root)

    for file in contents:
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            dirCnt = dirCnt + 1
        elif os.path.splitext(file)[1] == "txt":
            txtCnt = txtCnt + 1
        elif os.path.splitext(file)[1] == "pdf":
            pdfCnt = pdfCnt + 1
        else:
            print "Encountered unknown file: " + file
```

When I run this, I get no errors, but the script is clearly coded wrong. Here is the output I get:

```
Encountered unkown file: fizz
Encountered unkown file: buzz
Encountered unkown file: widgets

RESULTS
Text Files:    0
PDF Files:     0
Directories:   0
```

Anything jump out to you Pythonians out there? It looks like none of my logic (for detecting file vs. directory, as well as using `splitext` to grabs the file extension) is working here...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a job for [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) (if I understand correctly):

```
def count_pdf_txt(top):
    npdf = 0
    ntxt = 0
    ndir = 0
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(top):
        ndir += len(dirs)
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('txt'): #use `splitext` if you like.
                ntxt += 1
            elif f.endswith('pdf'):
                npdf += 1
            else:
                print "unknown"

    return npdf,ntxt,ndirs
```

---

Note that your version gives a wrong result because of the lines like:

```
 pdfCount = pdfCount + 1
```

inside your `get_counts` function.  This creates a new **local** variable which doesn't influence the **global** variable in any way.  In order to have your local variables change the global variables, you need to declare them as `global`.  e.g. `global pdfCount`.  However, the presence of a `global` keyword in your function should always make you think *"there's got to be a better way to do this"*.